nginx url rewrite rule escape question mark
I have this rule in nginx location / block
rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml\?date=([^/]+?)$ /sitemap.php?date=$1 last;

what I am trying to acomplish is to make
sitemap.php?date=01-01-2000 get accessed as sitemap.xml?date=01-02-2000
anything wrong with my query?
